# How to add effects in QTDialog during show/hide?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, qt4

Is there any way to add effects like dialog coming out to maximum size from tiny size when users clicks to show dialog !
like in iphoto when we request to open a dialog, it comes out in the same way!!!
The code which i'm using is :

```
  fade_effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
      this->setGraphicsEffect(fade_effect);
      animation = new QPropertyAnimation(fade_effect, "opacity");
      animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutQuad);
      animation->setDuration(5000);
      animation->setStartValue(1);
      animation->setEndValue(0.01);
      animation->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
      this->setWindowOpacity(0.5);
        //this->hide();
    //QDialog::reject();
```

Its not working in hiding case.

Comment: See if [`QPropertyAnimation`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpropertyanimation.html) would work for you.

Comment: The code example you added is controversial to what you had asked. If you want to get another information ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt Animation Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/animation-overview.html) gives you a lot of tools to create animation effects. Here is a sample how you can achieve your aim with `QPropetyAnimation` :

```
void YourWindowClass::showEvent(QShowEvent* e)
{
//create animation for "geometry" property
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(this, "geometry");

//duration in ms
animation->setDuration(500); 

//starting geometry
QRect startRect(900,500,100,100);

//final geometry
QRect endRect(750,350,400,400);

animation->setStartValue(startRect);
animation->setEndValue(endRect);

//starts animation which will be deleted when finished
animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

Comment: Hi please give look to the above code.Its not working.

Comment: What exacly doesn't work? I checked this code before posting.

Comment: your example is for moving a widget, not for changing opacity.

Comment: @BЈовић Where is it said that it's needed to change opacity? Read the question. The code was added later.

Comment: right. Besides his code doesn't reflect what is asked